# How can I create a view with a column as a CSV of multiple other columns?

Tags: sql, oracle, csv

I have a table with columns **bar1**, **bar2**, **bar3**.  Is there a way I can create a view with a column **bar** which is a CSV of **bar1**, **bar2**, and **bar3**?

Also, if **bar2** is null or **bar3** is null, then I don't want extraneous commas.

```
bar1 bar2 bar3   bar
---- ---- ----   ---
bat  bats bass = bat,bats,bass
bim  bis       = bim,bis
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it with a `case` expression.

```
select trim(trailing ',' from
            case when bar1 is not null then bar1||',' end ||
            case when bar2 is not null then bar2||',' end ||
            case when bar3 is not null then bar3 end) bar
from t
```

**[`Sample Demo`](http://rextester.com/FCXVH39450)**

Answer (score 2):

Some databases support a function called `concat_ws()` that does exactly this.

In Oracle, it is easy enough for three columns:

```
select trim(both ',' from replace(bar1 || ',' || bar2 || ',' || bar3, ',,', ',')) as bar
from . . .
```